# Dynamically creating multiple pictureboxes in vb

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to create 10 picture boxes dynamically

I am using a loop to create 10.

```
Dim FormBoxes As New List(Of PictureBox)
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MonthCalendar1.TodayDate = Now
    Dim Member As Integer = FormBoxes.Count - 1
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim Icon As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(My.Resources.icon1)
    Dim pb As New PictureBox
    pb.Width = 30
    pb.Height = 30
    pb.Top = 50
    pb.Left = 50
    pb.Image = Icon
    For num = 1 To 10
        Me.Controls.Add(pb)
    Next

End Sub
```

However only one picturebox is showing. I expect this is because they are in the same locations. How do i get the picture boxes to be arranged in a line not overlapping?

Comment: Your loop adds the same control (in this case `PictureBox`) repeatedly

Comment: It is the `New` keyword that creates an object.  How many times is the `New` keyword executed in your code?  If you expect a new object to be created in each iteration of the loop, where does the `New` keyword need to be?

Comment: If you are adding these in Form.Load, why not just do it at design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating only one picture box. If you want 5 picture boxes, create 5 picture boxes, i.e., you must repeat `New PictureBox` five times.

```
Dim AvailableIcon As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(My.Resources.available)
For num As Integer = 0 To 4
    Dim pb As New PictureBox With {
        .Width = 30,
        .Height = 30,
        .Top = 50,
        .Left = 50 + num * 35, 
        .Image = AvailableIcon
    }
    Me.Controls.Add(pb)
    FormBoxes.Add(pb)
Next
```

`.Left = 50 + num * 35` makes the pictures appear on the same line with 5 pixels distance between them.

Note that I am iterating from `0 To 4`. Therefore, `num * 35` will be zero for the first one.

Another option would be to add the picture boxes to a `FlowLayoutPanel` that arranges the pictures automatically.

Comment: You can set the `Name` property. But it will be easier to access them, if you add them to an array or a list. Add them to your already existing `FormsBoxes` list: `FormBoxes.Add(pb)`.